# Could not open symlink to port /dev/ttyACM*

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

tl;dr: I am unable to use my symlink to run rosserial since I would always get a message that there is no such file or directory with the symlink I created.

I've created a symlink to my arduino device using the following udev rules:

```
KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]", MODE="0666"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{serial}=="8563332343035180E191", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0043", ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Arduino (www.arduino.cc)", SYMLINK+="/tty-arduino-uno"
```

and I can see that the symbolic link has been created since I would get this output:

```
$ ls -la /dev/tty-arduino-uno 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jun 29 14:52 /dev/tty-arduino-uno -> ../ttyACM1
```

Now I wanted to run `rosserial_python` with this symlink but I would always get this error message when I run `rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/tty-arduino-uno`:

```
[ERROR] [1530309034.478989]: Error opening serial: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/tty-arduino-uno: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/tty-arduino-uno'
```

However, `rosserial_python` still works when I do

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM1
```

I get the following when I run `udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyACM1`:

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/tty/ttyACM1':
  KERNEL=="ttyACM1"
  SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
  DRIVER==""

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0':
  KERNELS=="1-1.1:1.0"
  SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
  DRIVERS=="cdc_acm"
  ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
  ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
  ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="02"
  ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
  ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
  ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="02"
  ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
  ATTRS{bmCapabilities}=="6"
  ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1':
  KERNELS=="1-1.1"
  SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
  DRIVERS=="usb"
  ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
  ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
  ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
  ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="02"
  ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
  ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
  ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="8"
  ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
  ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
  ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 2"
  ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0001"
  ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="c0"
  ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
  ATTRS{configuration}==""
  ATTRS{devnum}=="31"
  ATTRS{devpath}=="1.1"
  ATTRS{idProduct}=="0043"
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341"
  ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
  ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Arduino (www.arduino.cc)"
  ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
  ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
  ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
  ATTRS{serial}=="8563332343035180E191"
  ATTRS{speed}=="12"
  ATTRS{urbnum}=="15"
  ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1':
  KERNELS=="1-1"
  SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
  DRIVERS=="usb"
  ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
  ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
  ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
  ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
  ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
  ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
  ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
  ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
  ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
  ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
  ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0111"
  ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
  ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
  ATTRS{configuration}==""
  ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
  ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
  ATTRS{idProduct}=="0101"
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="1a40"
  ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
  ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
  ATTRS{product}=="USB 2.0 Hub"
  ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
  ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
  ATTRS{speed}=="480"
  ATTRS{urbnum}=="733"
  ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1':
  KERNELS=="usb1"
  SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
  DRIVERS=="usb"
  ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
  ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
  ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
  ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
  ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
  ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
  ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
  ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
  ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
  ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
  ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
  ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0404"
  ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
  ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
  ATTRS{configuration}==""
  ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
  ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
  ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
  ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
  ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
  ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.4.76-aero-1.2 xhci-hcd"
  ATTRS{maxchild}=="7"
  ATTRS{product}=="xHCI Host Controller"
  ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
  ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
  ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:14.0"
  ATTRS{speed}=="480"
  ATTRS{urbnum}=="74598"
  ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0':
  KERNELS=="0000:00:14.0"
  SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
  DRIVERS=="xhci_hcd"
  ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
  ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0330"
  ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="64"
  ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="1"
  ATTRS{device}=="0x22b5"
  ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="64"
  ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
  ATTRS{enable}=="1"
  ATTRS{irq}=="316"
  ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-3"
  ATTRS{local_cpus}=="f"
  ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
  ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x7270"
  ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x8086"
  ATTRS{vendor}=="0x8086"

looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
  KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
  SUBSYSTEMS==""
  DRIVERS==""
```

This tells me that there's something wrong with creating the symlink but I have not been able to figure out what is wrong. Has anyone else experienced the same problem?

EDIT: Added udevadm info

Thanks in advanced!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295819/could-not-open-symlink-to-port-/dev/ttyacm*/) by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-06-30**:
I notice the symlink points to a relative path. Not sure that matters, but what happens if you create the symlink manually (disable the `udev` rule for the test) and use the absolute path to `/dev/ttyACM1`?

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-07-05**:
Sorry for the delay. That works, but the whole point of me creating the symlink is I don't know what port my devices will be assigned to when I boot up. I have at least 2 devices connected through usb and the ports would change so I had the udev to match the device so I can assign a static name

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-07-05**:
Anyways, I found an alternative solution, which is to use the id from `/dev/serial/by-id`.I didn't have to add udev rules doing it this way. But thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-06**:
The point of the test was to see whether the symlink was actually created correctly, and whether relative symlinks would work. I know what `udev` is for and why you want to use it.

I would suggest to investigate why relative symlinks are being created and whether they are known to cause issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might try `SYMLINK+="tty-arduino-uno"` (i.e., no leading slash). The symlink gets created in `/dev` by default. It's worked many times for me, anyhow.

---

Originally posted by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) with karma: 567 on 2018-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2018-07-07**:
Agreed. (note that the existing symlink points to the wrong place: `../ttyACM1` instead of just `ttyACM1`)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-16**:
Which was what we were trying to diagnose by creating the symlink manually. But the OP seems to have already disappeared.

**Comment by [trixr4kdz](https://answers.ros.org/users/33122/trixr4kdz/) on 2018-08-09**:
Sorry about that, I got sidetracked. Yes, this was what was happening and your solution works.